# Splitting one column into multiple columns with a re-usable function in KQL

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I'm very new to KQL and I could have completely the wrong idea about the method I'm using to solve this problem so feel free to suggest a better way but I'll try my best to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I am querying a particular dataset with many different queries but one consistent thing about it is one of the columns needs to be parsed from a crazy text field into multiple columns.

The columns of the the original data are things like "Computer", "User", then a large string field like this:

```
"Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=23, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)"
```

So I've defined a function(which works when not run in the function) to parse that string column into multiple string columns:

```
Let parseEventData = (EventData:string){
EventData
| parse EventText with * "resourceName=" resourceName ", totalSlices=" totalSlices:long * "sliceNumber=" sliceNumber:long * "lockTime=" lockTime ", releaseTime=" releaseTime:date "," * "previousLockTime=" previousLockTime:date ")" *  
| project resourceName, totalSlices, sliceNumber, lockTime, releaseTime, previousLockTime
}
```

So now I want to output a new table which is "Computer","User","resourceName", "totalSlices", "sliceNumber", "lockTime", "releaseTime", "previousLockTime"
e.g. the original table but with this column parsed out.

I've tried things like:

```
Events
| where parameter == "blah"
| project name,computer,parseEventData(EventData)
```

But it will give the error

```
Operator source expression should be table or column
```

Is there a way to add a table to 2 existing columns like this or am I barking up the wrong tree?

*Note:*

*This does work if I don't use a function at all and just use another pipe and do the parsing there. The issue being is that I will be using this type of Parsing for almost every query I do and I feel like it could be really messy / time consuming to write out the entire thing each time! Hope that all makes sense.*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
let EventData = datatable(Computer:string, User:string, EventText:string)
[
    "C1", "U1", "Event: NotifySliceRelease (resourceName=PipelineScheduler, totalSlices=27, sliceNumber=23, lockTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, releaseTime=02/17/2016 08:40:01, previousLockTime=02/17/2016 08:39:01)"
];
let parseEventData = (T:(EventText:string)) {
    T
    | parse EventText with * "resourceName=" resourceName ", totalSlices=" totalSlices:long * "sliceNumber=" sliceNumber:long * "lockTime=" lockTime ", releaseTime=" releaseTime:date "," * "previousLockTime=" previousLockTime:date ")" *  
    | extend resourceName, totalSlices, sliceNumber, lockTime, releaseTime, previousLockTime
    | project-away EventText
};
parseEventData(EventData)
```

| Computer | User | resourceName | totalSlices | sliceNumber | lockTime | releaseTime | previousLockTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | U1 | PipelineScheduler | 27 | 23 | 02/17/2016 08:40:01 | 2016-02-17 08:40:01.0000000 | 2016-02-17 08:39:01.0000000 |

Alternatively, you can use the `invoke` operator as follows:

```
EventData
| where <condition>
| invoke parseEventData()
```

Comment: So I guess I do:
`parseEventData(Events| where parameter == "blah")`

for my query? Or is there a better way?

But yes, this definitely is looking good so far!

Comment: See the updated answer, which includes a reference to `invoke`, if you prefer that syntax. Performance should be identical

Comment: Perfect :) That's exactly the type of thing I'm looking for! Thank you